# Execute code after cucumber cli main method to generate report

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to use cucumber with selenium+java and invoking cucumber through cli api like :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Main.main(new String[] {"-p","pretty",... }

//code needs to be executed after cucumber main is here
}
```

I want to execute some part of code once cucumber main execution is completed. But program terminates once cucumber finishes execution. How can I execute piece of code written after cucumber cli main.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you may need to rewrite the cumcumber cli api main method. Below is the sample code may help you:

```
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;

public class Execute extends Main{

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Throwable {
        String[] options = {"-g", "StepDfination","--plugin","/path/to/json/report.json", "-t", "<your tag what you need to test", "/path/to/your/feature.feature"};

        byte exitstatus = run(options, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        //Do somethings after all cucumber test finished.
        DriverUtil.closeDriver();
        ReportUtil.ouputHtmlReport("/path/to/json/report.json");

        System.exit(exitstatus);
    }

}
```

Comment: what I simply did was reuse cucumber cli definition and simply commented last line where system.exit is called. It worked like charm !! :D